# Swap element in list to control the event system

Tags: c#, arrays

**My problem:**

I have a list of interfaces that are called when certain event happens (let's say On1AEvent). Iterating through all elements in the list makes another object fire another major event which some objects may be interested in (let's call him On1BEvent). This event is expected to be fired AFTER all objects get the On1AEvent, but it fires before On1AEvent is finished calling all objects.

This makes sense because the object that fires the event is somewhere in the middle of the list (which was populated dynamically and have no control of how is populated).

**The solution:**

One solution is that I would iterate through the interfaces when are populated and put the object that fires On1BEvent to the last position. This will make sure that all objects receive On1AEvent before On1BEvent which it makes perfect sense.

**Question:**

Am I complicating or is there some other maybe easier way to do this?

**Question 2:**

is there some (already built-in which I may not be aware of) method that swaps or changes the index of the element in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider using a priority to order the events.

Comment: Good idea. How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: There are lots of possible solutions. I don't know enough about your situation to select one. As I suggested before, one option is to use priorities when registering event handlers so that the one that needs to fire last can be sorted to the end of the list. Another option is to implement before and after event handlers (this event is about to start / this event just completed) and register the one that needs to run last as an after event.